# To draw a function within an interval

Tags: graphics, functions

I need to draw this function: z=f(x), where z=tanh(y) and y=sin(x), within a range of x(-2Pi,2Pi)?
Should I use "Plot" function or some other built-in functions?

Thank you

Comment: Is something wrong with `Plot[Tanh[Sin[x]],{x,-2Pi,2Pi}]`? Or is your goal to have `y` play a role in the plot as well?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Is this a Mathematica question?

Comment: Oh, not "a" but "z", I made a mistake. Will edit. So axis should be x,y,z

Answer (score 3):

It is still a bit unclear exactly what kind of an answer would help you most. The way I read the last comment is that you want all $x,y,z$ to be plotted. In other words, you want a 3D-plot. The function `Plot3D` is typically used to plot a function of two variables, when you want to see the surface $z=f(x,y)$. Here you you seem to have a single variable $x$ only such that both $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$ (in your case $z$ is really a function of $y$, but we can turn it into a function of $x$ as a composition).

---

Assuming my "guess" above is correct, then
I would use `ParametricPlot3D` for this job. Like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sin[x], Tanh[Sin[x]]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, {-0.5, 0,
     0.5}}]
```

producing the output

[image]

You can play with the `BoxRatios`-option to adjust the dimensions of the resulting box to your liking.

But, as you see, this may not be very illuminating, because it is difficult to tell exactly how that curve twists in the 3D-space. If I were in need of illustrating the functional dependences between $x$ and $y$ as well as $y$ and $z$, I would add to the same picture the surfaces $y=\sin x$ and $z=\tanh y$, but drawn a bit transparent. Something like:

```
kappyra = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sin[x], Tanh[Sin[x]]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, 
  Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, {-0.5, 
     0, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]

surf1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Tanh[y]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -1, 
   1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]

surf2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sin[x], z}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {z, -0.8, 
   0.8}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]

Show[{kappyra, surf1, surf2}]
```

yielding

[image]

The upshot is that the curve is the intersection of the two surfaces $y=\sin x$ and $z=\tanh y$. My experience is that the resulting picture looks better if you draw the curve of intersection separately.

Don't know if this is worthwhile in the present case? In this range of $y$, the hyperbolic tangent is pretty flat. With a wilder function in place of $\tanh y$ these extras might make the final picture more informative. Also, feel free to adjust the `Opacity`-parameters to your liking.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the finer points of Mathematica-programming (Pascal programmer from the 90s here), but I have a bit of experience coercing Mathematica to draw pictures suited to teaching (vector) calculus and college algebra. I realize that some of my latest answers on Mathematica.SE have been to questions that could attract criticism at sister sites like Math.SE. I simply don't know the local do's and do-not's :-(. If I cross any lines, somebody please tap my shoulder and/or point me at a resource covering related pitfalls. I will adjust.